# Alternative to Outlook 2013 in Windows?

Tags: windows, email, email-client, outlook

On my Windows box, I've been using Outlook 2013 to access five IMAP accounts, some of which have thousands of emails in them. Over time, Outlook has begun to perform so poorly that there is now a delay of over ten seconds from the time that I click on an email to the time that it's displayed. This is on a machine with 16GB RAM, an i7, an SSD-- Outlook is the only program that exhibits performance problems.

Can anyone recommend a Windows email app that performs well with large amounts of email, and includes good search functionality as well? Thanks very much!

Comment: Your requirements are pretty thin.  But, event with that, thousands of emails is likely to cause a problem with any product that is suggested.

Comment: I don't have this problem with Mail.app on my MacBook. It's only when I'm on Windows, using Outlook, that I run into problems.

Comment: Try emClient app.

Comment: Mozilla Thunderbird can handle multiple accounts, but I'd suggest cleaning up the mailboxes, by organizing messages in folders, by bringing them local, or by selecting the oldest year or two (or otherwise rarely accessed correspondence) and moving them *en masse* to an archive folder.

Comment: Sorry, I never mentioned Thunderbird. I have used it extensively, as well as Postbox which is based on it, and ultimately moved away from both of them due to performance issues and lackluster search functionality, as well as general stability problems in the case of Thunderbird.

Comment: PHPst, would you mind posting that suggestion as an answer? I had never heard of eM Client and am having a lot of luck with it; if possible I'd like to give you credit. Thanks!